# Where/how can I obtain the computational features of a non-CUDA GPU?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, specifications

<sub>(Please don't recommend a specific product or service kthxbye)</sub>

I'm considering getting a discrete OpenCL-oriented GPU (i.e. not NVIDIA). Now, with CUDA GPUs (i.e. NVIDIA...), you have the 'Compute Capability' figure, which you can easily [translate into concrete compute-related features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Version_features_and_specifications) - but I can't seem to find something parallel in the OpenCL world. You can find overall bandwidth, or a sort-of-cooked figure for maximum number of work-items executing in parallel (it's a cooked number for reasons such as not telling you what you can do with each of these between clock cycles. I can double the figure by doubling the number of cycles per op) - but not the very long and specific set of micro-features (which are mostly independent from the GPU's macro-features).

I'm interested in an answer regarding both integrated and discrete, and not just in NVIDIA's contender AMD. It's specifically interesting for me to look at supposedly 'weak' GPUs since I care more about the architecture than how much I can actually crunch with it.

Comment: You can use `clGetDeviceInfo` to get information about an OpenCL device. https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html

Comment: @void_ptr: That only works if I have the card already...

Comment: Try to propose any good estimation technique for determining compute capability of some chip with unknown architecture, and most likely you'll end up with conclusion, that there is no such technique.

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan: You know, OpenCL already has some device attributes for which some devices have an 'undefined' value; and it has some very GPU-specific attributes. So, I see no reason not to have the range of CUDA attributes mirrored in OpenCL.

Comment: Nvidia knows everything about it's own hardware & software, so they can provide performance index. Between multiple vendors, it's very difficult to do - that's why benchmarks exist.

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan: This has nothing to do with performance index. Take something like the maximum number of 32-bit registers a single work-item can use. That just part of the design spec of a GPU. Why can't I see a table of that on, say, AMD's website by card?